# Send binary data from one application to another in android, securely

Tags: android

I have developed an application A that has all the data (text files, images, contacts etc.) in encrypted form. My application B needs to access this data of app A. No other application should be able to get that data.

What I want is, when app B requests data from app A, app A decrypt the requested data and send it to app B. Means, it needs to be two-way communication. Interface of app A should not be opened during all this process (maybe I can use service in app A).

I am done with encryption/decryption, but stuck in inter-app communication. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use content provider to share data from single app and to retrieve code from your second app.

Look at [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm) and share same content URL from other app to retrieve encrypted data.

Comment: App A's data is stored on sdcard in encrypted form. I want app A to decrypt it and share it with app B, on request. What I get from your suggestion is, App A should place decrypted data into content provider to share it with app B.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you have to store encrypted data into content provider from App A and get that encrypted data from App B and Decrypt it . This way you can securely share data between your app A and B.

Comment: Ok, got that. Thank you very much.

Now, I have developed sample applications (without enc/dec), to test inter-app communication. I am able to only open the data from app B. Can I store that data into some byte array in app B, for later use?

Comment: Yes, why not. Convert that stream into byte array and store where you want.